# How to migrate MVC project with full .Net framework to Microsoft.Net.Sdk project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I'm trying to migrate my MVC project with full .Net framework 4.7.2 to Microsoft.Net.Sdk style project.

It's ok and it compiles.

To launch it, I had a lauchSettings.json file :

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject.WebMvc5": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\iisexpress.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "/path:\"$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\" /port:12345"
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that the application is recylcled at every HTTP request.

I can see it with my breakpoint in Application_Start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
This issue was I was logging in my project folder.

If the files change, the App cycle restart...

To resolve, I removed the files of logs...